# Как войти под root MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Я уже что только не пробовал. Все методы восстановления, смены перепробовал, заходил в таблицу user и сам вбивал пароль. Не удается мне войти!

Comment: Под какой системой крутится MySQL сервер?

Comment: Windows, но как мне кажется тут это не играет роли. MySQL в OpenServer'e если что.

Comment: Такое пробовали - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html ?

Comment: @borodatych нет, не помогло. Хост у рута установлен %, но это тоже не должно его касаться.

Comment: Пробовал через консоль, говорит Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `localhost` использовать `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Это же тоже самое, но я попробовал и такой же эффект, то же самое сообщение

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno ?

Comment: Там те же ссылки приводят, что и вы.
Выполняю запрос по последней инструкции в документации
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('blabla');
Получаю 0 rows affected

Comment: Воспользовался другим модулем, версией 5.6, где конфиги чистые.

Comment: @borodatych наткнулся на статью, в которой говорится что с локальной машины нельзя подключится к БД имея пользователя с параметром хоста '%'
http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/16.html

Comment: Оформите это в виде ответа на свой вопрос, другим будет полезно и вам бонус ;)

Answer (score 2):

Был пользователь root с хостом '%'. Из статьи [тык](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/16.html) понял, что с локальной машины подключиться к пользователю с хостом '%' нельзя. Можно создать идентичного пользователя, но с localhost и теми же привилегиями.